# Django ORM & compound primary keys. Relationship status: "It's complicated."

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-orm

I have a (legacy) database with the following tables. How do i follow the relationship from the orders object to the delivery_adress in Django's views and templates?

In SQL, i would simply use join delivery_adress on customer_fk = customer_fk and customer_fk = customer_fk, but how does it work in the Django ORM?

The tables are defined like this (i tried to mark down the FK relationships):

```
 orders
id | ordernr | product | amount | customer (FK) | delivery_adress (FK)
---+---------+---------+--------+---------------+---------------------
 1 | 20      | 5       | 200    | 1             | 1
 2 | 21      | 3       | 400    | 2             | 1
 3 | 22      | 2       | 20     | 2             | 2
 4 | 23      | 1       | 1      | 3             | 1
                                       |               |
 customer   ---------------------------                |
id | name  |----                                       |
---+-------+   |                                       |
 1 | John  |   |                                       |
 2 | Steve |   |                              ---------
 3 | Guy   |   |                             |
 4 | Joe   |   |                             |
               |                             |
 delivery_adress
customer (PK/FK) | delivery_adress(PK) | adress
-----------------+---------------------+-------
1                | 1                   | SF
2                | 1                   | LA
2                | 2                   | NY
3                | 1                   | CH
```

The Model delivery_adress is:

```
class Delivery_adress(models.Model):
    customer= models.ForeignKey(Customer, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='adresse', primary_key=True)
    delivery_adress = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True)
    #... other stuff ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        unique_together = (('customer', 'delivery_adress'),)
```

Comment: Django doesn't directly support compound keys so adding `primary_key=True` to both fields isn't going to work.  you need to use a third-party solution like https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. This would work if the relationship was directly between the two tables, but the customer FK breaks it. I think i will look into Manager.raw, maybe RAW SQL will work for me.

Comment: have another look, they show an example where an FK field is part of the compound key https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey#abstract-foreignkey--field-extensions-syntax